# MS access 2013 - java String

Tags: java, string, ms-access-2013

I am using netbeans and MS Access 2013. I have written a simple program to store the value from a String variable into a database. Database name is users.accdb.
Table : user1  Fields: uid Type: (Short Text)

String name=" ";
try {

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver=
{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
Dbq=F:\\users.accdb");

Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

stmt.execute("insert into user1(uid) values("+name+")");

conn.close(); stmt.close();
}catch(SQLException se){
                       se.printStackTrace();
                       }
```

1. When I place any String with alphabets like "frank" in the string variable name, it is not stored in the database.
2. If I place String with numbers like "123" in the string variable, it is stored exactly without any error.
3. If i simply mention a string in the query within ' '.. it is stored.

when something is not stored in the database, I get this : [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'frank'

Have anyone faced something like this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes in your insert statement. So instead of

```
insert into user1(uid) values("+name+")"
```

Use

```
insert into user1(uid) values(\'"+name+"\')"
```

You query is vulnerable to SQL injection. If you want to avoid that and get rid of quotes missing like above, you should use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Comment: After I placed quotes as u said, everything is fine. Is it a new syntax ? .. The syntax which I used seemed to work with MS Access 2010 and 07. Kindly explain.

Comment: No its not. You need quotes for character fields.